# Divs ocultas enquanto outras estão visíveis

Tags: div, display

Eu vi algumas outras perguntas semelhantes, mas talvez meu caso seja mais específico.

No cabeçalho existe:

Faça LOGIN ou Cadastre-se (caso não estiver logado)

e

MINHA CONTA / SAIR (logado no sistema)

Facilmente os links eu consigo criar, mas gostaria que quando estivesse logado, automaticamente aparecem "MINHA CONTA / SAIR" e quando estiver deslogado aparece "Faça LOGIN ou Cadastre-se"

Comment: Isso vai depender de quais tecnologias você está usando. Pesquise como trabalhar com "sessões" na tecnologia que você usa.

Answer (score -2):

O código que vou te mostrar agora vai usar Java Script, já que você está falando em WEB.

```
<div id="menu">
     <a href="#"> Login </a>
     <a href="$"> Cadastre-se </a>
</div>

<div id="menu">
   <a href="#"> Minha Conta </a>
   <a href="#"> Sair </a>
</div>
```

Criei duas divs cada uma para cada caso, se não estiver logado deve aparecer a primeira, caso contrário deve aparecer a segunda certo ?
Vamos para o Java Script que vai gerenciar essa "troca" de menus.

```
<script>
 const estado = "deslogado"
 const menus = document.QuerySelectorAll('#menu')

if(estado == "deslogado"){
menus[0].style.display = "block"
menus[1].style.display = "none"
}else {
menus[0].style.display = "none"
menus[1].style.dispaly = "block"
}

</script>
```

O funcionamento desse script simples, depende sempre do valor da variável "estado" que você pode modificar usando uma função simples como.

```
function alterarEstado(){
      if(estado == "deslogado"){
           estado = "logado"
      }else{
           estado = "deslogado
        }
}
```

Você pode chamar essa função em um "onclick" dentro do teu HTML ou dentro de um eventListener dentro do próprio Java Script que vai estar escutando o botão de login.